# comparing two csv files

Tags: python, csv

```
import csv
with t1 = open('old.csv', 'r') as f1, t2 = open('new.csv', 'r') as f2:
    # skip headers
    next(f1),next(f2)d
    r1 = csv.reader(f1)
    # make set of strings matching format of file2
    st = set("{},{}".format(row[0], row[2]) for row in r1)
    # iterate over every line in file2
    # and check if the line appears in the set
    for line in f2:
        if line.rstrip() in st:
            print(line)
```

this code is not what  i want CSV  ,i want a python code for compare two csv files columns and 
if their is similar item i need to create a csv file with  the similar items assosiated id..

Comment: Would you mind tell what is your definition of similarity?

Comment: one csv contains certain keywords and other csv also have some keywords, am ,looking for the matching keywords

Comment: I ll explain it properly, their are 2 csv files the first csv have 2 row (sl no , and keywords) and second csv have number of rows and specifically a row named as products, i need to check if the key words in the first csv match with the product in the second csv , if it match then i need to print a csv file with the product name and id (id is also one of the rows in second csv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are okay with using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/api.html)

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'sr':[1,2],'keywords':['keyword1','keyword2']}) # can read a csv1 using pd.read_csv('path_to_your_csv1')
df
    keywords    sr
0   keyword1    1
1   keyword2    2
```

Load another csv of products

```
df2=pd.DataFrame({'sr':[1,2],'product':['keyword1 is in this product','no key word present']})# can read a csv1 using pd.read_csv2('path_to_your_csv2')
df2
    product                    sr
0   keyword1 is in this product 1
1   no key word present         2
```

Apply search criteria

```
     product                   sr
0   keyword1 is in this product 1
```

You can export the resultant dataframe to a new csv.

```
df3=df2[df2['product'].str.contains("|".join(df.keywords))]
df3.to_csv('your_path_to_new_csv',index=False)
```

Comment: The csv file is creating but we are now using the join function right, i need to find the product id from the second csv  where the product which have the same key word from the first csv.